# Disable checkboxes based on click

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes that I want to disable only if a particular checkbox has been selected within that group. I'm thinking I need to name the checkboxes with a distinct name and filter through the others based upon a click, but also hoping the smart folks of stackoverflow might have a quicker solution.

**HTML**

```
<td>Team 1 <br>Team 2</td><td> 
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id=">+155 / 2.55 </a><input type="checkbox" id=0 class="parlay" value=><br>
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id=">-175 / 1.57 </a> <input type="checkbox" class="parlay" id=0  value=>
</td><td> 
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id=">+3 100 / 2.00 </a><input type="checkbox" id=0 class="parlay" value=><br>
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id=">-3 -120 / 1.83</a><input type="checkbox" id=0 class="parlay" value=>
</td><td> 
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id="> Over 50.5 -107 / 1.93</a><input type="checkbox" id=0 class="parlay" value=><br>
    <a class='iframe' href="bet-nfl?game_id=">Under 50.5 -107 / 1.93 </a><input type="checkbox" id=0 class="parlay" value=>
</td></tr>
```

**jquery (so far)**

```
$(function(){
 $('input:checkbox.parlay').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    alert ($this.attr("id")); //return 0 if a checkbox is selected
    //$(this).prop("checked", false); // <--I'm doing this wrong
 });
```

Comment: Gotcha - so if I made them 0_a, 0_b, 0_c, etc -> how would I recursively disable them based on 0_d being selected (as an example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You've to clean up your HTML, it's not valid and could cause errors.
2. Please create a fiddle next time (http://jsfiddle.net).
3. Every element needs an **unique ID** and a **group**. In my example I chose the data-group attribute.

That should be your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/B9Xxj/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" data-group="1"/> #1, Group 1 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" data-group="2"/> #2, Group 2 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="3" data-group="3"/> #3, Group 3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="4" data-group="3"/> #4, Group 3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="5" data-group="3"/> #5, Group 3 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="6" data-group="4"/> #6, Group 4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="7" data-group="4"/> #7, Group 4 <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="8" data-group="5"/> #8, Group 5 <br/>
```

-

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    var group = $(this).data("group"); // group ID 
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked"); // status checked/unchecked
    $("input[type=checkbox][data-group="+ group +"]").prop("checked", checked); // check/uncheck!
});
```

Good luck with it! ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the response and code, looks (and works) great!